# Get the class(ID) name of a specific eclipse component

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to develop an eclipse plugin by extending some of the current functionalities. For example, I would like to add a view in the Java category.
What I find difficult is searching for the elements plugs/extension points names(not sure if I use the terminology right). But here's an example:

I created a view and added it to the Java perspective ( Menu->Window->Show View->Other...->Java.

```
   <extension
      point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
      <category
            id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.java"
            name="Show view">
      </category>
      <view
            category="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.java"
            id="start.startCategory"
            class="start.ViewClass"
            name="viewExtension">
      </view>
   </extension>
```

Now the question is, how can I easily get those `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.java` alike extension points names(for a category, a view, an editor...)?

Comment: Look at [Eclipse Plugin Spy](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#pluginspy) for UI components. For the rest you need to look at the plugin.xml for the appropriate plugin.

Comment: Thank you greg, that is good information!